# enumerate items and table side by side

Tags: tables, enumerate

How to make enumerate items and a table side by side like the effect in the image which is from CLRS P.61.
[image: correct example]

I have tried to make every row a table in each enumerate item, but the effect is not the same as what I expect.

And manually adding a. b. c. in the first column of a table could not solve the problem either because it will make the indentation wrong.
Here is a MWE to show the wrong indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{L{1em}C{3em}*{6}{C{3em}|}}
& A & B & O & o & \Omega & \omega & \Theta \\ \hline
a. & {\lg^k{n}} & n^{\epsilon} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
b. & n^k & c^n &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
c. & \sqrt{n} & n^{\sin{n}} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\textit{\alph*}}.]
\item $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$
\item $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$
\item $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: wrong indentation]

In the image above ,the first red line could not be horizontally aligned with the second red line.

Comment: I guess adding the letters in their own column is the easiest way to go.  What do you mean by "it will make the indentation wrong"?  Please edit your question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), including the additional column, and describe precisely what goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I add a MWE to show the wrong indentation after editing the problem description.

Comment: @Christophe: You completely changed the question since in the first version the was no separate enumeration environment :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Really sorry for only obscurely mentioning about the indentation problem in the first version!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This uses a new column type called `E` (like enumerate) and a counter called `rowcounter` which increases in each row, the first row is omitted here. The table column is left aligned, but `r` - type might be better!

Please note that this will fail after 26 rows of course since the `\alph` output cannot handle counter values larger than 26. The `\alphalph` command from `alphalph` package could be useful then.

Please fill in in the math content yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{rowcounter}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\bfseries \ifnum\value{rowcounter} > 0 \alph{rowcounter}.\fi\stepcounter{rowcounter}}l}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{E*{7}{c}}
  & A & B & C & D & E & F & G\tabularnewline
  & \tabularnewline
  & \tabularnewline
  & \tabularnewline
  & \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{rowcounter}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\ifnum\value{rowcounter} > 0 \text{\textbf{\textit{\alph{rowcounter}}}.}\fi\stepcounter{rowcounter}}r}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}


\newlength{\enumindent}
\setlength{\enumindent}{\leftmargin}
\addtolength{\enumindent}{1.7\tabcolsep}



\begin{document}
$
\begin{array}{DC{3em}*{6}{C{3em}|}}
   & A & B & O & o & \Omega & \omega & \Theta \\ \hline
 & {\lg^k{n}} & n^{\epsilon} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 & n^k & c^n &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 & \sqrt{n} & n^{\sin{n}} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\textit{\alph*}}.,leftmargin=\enumindent]
\item $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$
\item $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$
\item $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But like I said, it also has the indentation problem. I made a [WME](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5653e844db798e5822ac0d44) to show that. I want the first group of enumerate items to be vertically aligned with the second group.

Comment: @Christophe: You rather want horizontal alignment, not the vertical one!

Comment: @Christophe: See my update please

Comment: Thanks for update. Except for manually setting the rowcounter to zero when I have more than one this kind of table, the solution is perfect.

Comment: Well, how should TeX know you want to use the rowcounter stuff? I can think about it, but at the moment I am occupied with other issues ;-)